# Python string to list?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to convert string to a list

```
 str = "ab(1234)bcta(45am)in23i(ab78lk)"
```

Expected Output

```
 res_str = ["ab","bcta","in23i"]
```

I tried removing brackets from str.

```
 re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', str)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a negated character class with a lookahead:

```
>>> s = "ab(1234)bcta(45am)in23i(ab78lk)"
>>> print (re.findall(r'[^()]+(?=\()', s))
['ab', 'bcta', 'in23i']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `[^()]+`: Match 1 of more of any character that is not `(` and `)`
- `(?=\()`: Lookahead to assert that there is a `(` ahead

Answer (score 2):

So many options here. One possibility would be using `split`:

```
import re
str = "ab(1234)bcta(45am)in23i(ab78lk)"
print(re.split(r'\(.*?\)', str)[:-1])
```

Returns:

```
['ab', 'bcta', 'in23i']
```

---

A second option would be to split by all paranthesis and slice your resulting array:

```
import re
str = "ab(1234)bcta(45am)in23i(ab78lk)"
print(re.split('[()]', str)[0:-1:2])
```

Where `[0:-1:2]` means to *start* at index 0, to *stop* at second to last index, and *step* two indices.

Answer (score 1):

You may match all alphanumeric characters followed by a `(` :

```
>>> re.findall('\w+(?=\()',str)
['ab', 'bcta', 'in23i']
```

or using `re.sub` as you were:

```
>>> re.sub('\([^)]+\)',' ',str).split()
['ab', 'bcta', 'in23i']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use re.split

```
import re

str = "ab(1234)bcta(45am)in23i(ab78lk)"

print(re.split('\(.*?\)', str))
```

Returns:

```
['ab', 'bcta', 'in23i', '']
```

If you want to get rid of empty strings in your list, you may use a filter:

```
print(list(filter(None, re.split('\(.*?\)', str))))
```

Returns:

```
['ab', 'bcta', 'in23i']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of complexity :

```
>>>> str = "ab(1234)bcta(45am)in23i(ab78lk)"
>>>> res_str = [y[-1] for y in [ x.split(')') for x in str.split('(')]][0:-1]
['ab', 'bcta', 'in23i']
```